# checking whether the number is in phone contacts are not

Tags: iphone

i want to check whether the given number is in phone book or not programatically .

i am able to display the contact name of the given number if it is exists in phone book but the program crashes when there is no contact with that number in phone book ...
but what i want is to display name if it exists in phone book..... and display the number if if is not in phone book......
and my code is as follows....

NSMutableArray *names = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *phonenumbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
NSArray *thePeople = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

NSString *name;
for (id person in thePeople)
{

    name = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    NSLog(@"!!!!!! name ---> %@",name);
    ABMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    int count1=ABMultiValueGetCount(multi);
    NSLog(@"%d",count1);

    if ([name length]>0 && count1!=0) 
    {
        NSString *beforenumber = (NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, 0);
        NSLog(@" contacts:%@",beforenumber );
        NSString* removed1=[beforenumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-"withString:@""];
        NSString* removed2=[removed1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")"withString:@""];
        NSString* removed3=[removed2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" "withString:@""];
        NSString* removed4=[removed3 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"("withString:@""];
        NSString* removed5=[removed4 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+"withString:@""];

        [names addObject:name];
        [phonenumbers addObject:removed5];

    }

}
int barindex = -1;
barindex = [phonenumbers indexOfObject:number];
if(barindex == -1)
    return number;
else
return [names objectAtIndex:barindex];
```

can any one please help me how to do that.............

thank you.......

Comment: Are you working on a caller id?

Comment: no i have a text box in that i will enter the number manually and i have to display the name if the number exists otherwise display i have to display the number.....

Comment: do you need that as long as the user is typing or when he press a button after the number is entered?

Comment: yes after pressing a button it should check....

Comment: Give me a couple of minutes. I will answer you.

Comment: @user564963 : Share your crash log ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code would be improved but I think that is what you need.
[Sample Code](http://jorgedelprado.com.ar/phonenumbersearch.zip)